# Chrome vs FF Sub-Pixel Rendering

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox

After banging my head trying to figure out why a website looked different at different screen resolutions, I finally realized that it was because Browser's don't actually respect the values you put in the styles.  Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/daneren2005/6c5ozj1q/1/ where all I did was have a element `<div style="width: 8.932px; height: 11.1635px;"></div>` and output it's width with `alert($('div')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);`.

In that fiddle FF outputs 8.933334350585938 and Chrome outputs 8.921875.  The actual width I put in was 8.932px so FF is off by 0.001 and Chrome is off by 0.01.  Is there any way to get div's to actually be the width I am telling them to be?  This isn't a problem for 99.9% of the cases, but there is that tiny percentage which are placed just perfectly so it is showing differently for different users.  PS This is not for a presentation/news type website where I can just cover up for it.  It is for a website where the user generates their own content and there are an infinite number of ways this can cause issues.  Think http://fabricjs.com/.

Comment: I would say (seriously) to not accept more than one decimal as browsers will round this to the nearest integer value (given ppi/dpi/px/device, etc.) simply because device screens don't handle anything beyond whole pixels. More decimal places only makes sense when working with 3D vectors and such, but they too will finally get translated to whole pixels. I wouldn't worry to much about more decimal places. In FF as well as CH you will end up with 9px for 8.93333 and 8.921875

Comment: The problem is I use it for calculations which do cause issues.  I understand that the position will not actually be rendered on the screen as a sub-pixel, but when I am calculating if item one intersects with item two, I need it to respect the values I put in.

Comment: In that case I'd have a look at threed.js or d3.js which are tried and accepted 3D Javascript libraries with, what I imagine, proper calculation routines converting values between world, local, local and screen space (either 2D or 3D). I suck at vector and collision detecting math, so I would digg into those libraries. One thing I can think of is multiplying the input with a large number (like 10K or 100K) and scale down at screen output, but as I said, math^@#*_@#?? (And by looking at the reactions thusfar, others too).